# CSS selector for the first element of class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I choose only the first button in this code?

It's even more nested in my case, but this code is also a problem for me.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="some_class">
    <span>abc</span>
    <button class="btn">...</button>
  </div>
  <div class="some_class">
    <span>abc</span>
    <button class="btn">...</button>
  </div>
  <div class="some_class">
    <span>abc</span>
    <button class="btn">...</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) pseudo class.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nUZXK/)

```
.container .some_class:first-child button {
    background:black;
}
```

Alternatively, assuming that the markup can be different, you *might* need to use something like this to ensure that the first button is selected even if `.some_class` isn't the first element. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/Hsa7N/)

```
.container :first-child button {
    background:black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
.container .some_class:first-child button {
    /* rules here */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cUu82/1/

you could just use .some_class:first-child button as well if these are the only ones on the page

The first-child (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) will select the first some_class div which was probably your only issue